# Basic jQuery slideUp/slideDown help

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, text, submit

I was wondering if there was a function that I can add to this, that would show the data again, as in make it slide back down or something after a given set of time so you can go back and re-enter your data.

It currently just slides up after submit, and then shows the text.

```
 $("#help").slideUp(function() {
$("#help").before('<div class="failMessage">SOME FAIL TEXT HERE</div>');
setTimeout(ShowControlsHideFailMessage,5000);
 });

    function ShowControlsHideFailMessage()
    {
       $("#help").slideDown();
       $('.failMessage').addClass('hidden');
    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want your form to slideUp (which you have done) and after 5 seconds slideDown?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want. Is there a way to make it hide the text after it slides back down as well?

Comment: @Joey: I made the change necessary to fix the slideDown and hide the message.  my answer below explains the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code sample below will use the setTimeout function to call $("#help").slideDown() after 5 seconds.  Also, If you want to hide the "FAIL TEXT", I'd suggest using a CSS class for that message like this:

```
$("#help").slideUp(function() {
   $("#help").before('<div class="failMessage">SOME FAIL TEXT HERE</div>');
   setTimeout(ShowControlsHideFailMessage, 5000);
});

function ShowControlsHideFailMessage()
{
   $("#help").slideDown();
   $('.failMessage').addClass('hidden');
}
```

You can use the class failMessage for red fonts or anything special to that message and then create a hidden class that sets the display to none.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't timeout haha. It does a slideUp, and then immediately slides back down, but after it slides back down, the text is still above it.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from the setTimeout function as updated above...  should read setTimeout(ShowControlsHideFailMessage, 5000);

Comment: I updated the question with the full code that I am using if that helps, I think I am doing so much wrong!

Comment: @Joey: It was a parenthesis error in my answer.  I've corrected...  You should be good to go now.

Comment: Actually it works, thanks! Also could you tell me why it's showing 

 $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn(100);

Again? Do I just have to put a div class on that as well?

Comment: @Joey: Not sure...  if you were to post your HTML snippets in addition to your current js, I could take a peak.

Comment: Posted, towards the bottom. That's ALL of it, as the rest is php, etc. I'm going to try a fadeout, it seems as if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way:

```
var failMessage = $('<div class="failMessage" />');
failMessage.text('SOME FAIL TEXT HERE');
//Create the failMessage beforehand

$("#help")
    .slideUp(function() {
        $(this).before(failMessage);
    })
    .delay(5000)
    .slideDown(function () {
        failMessage.hide();
    }​);​
```